# python input for itertools.product

Tags: python

Looking for a way to simulate nested loops (or a cartesian product) i came across the itertools.product function. 
i need a function or piece of code that receive a list of integers as input and returns a specific generator.

example:
input = [3,2,4] -> gen = product(xrange(3),xrange(2),xrange(4))
or
input = [2,4,5,6] -> gen = product(xrange(2),xrange(4),xrange(5),xrange(6))

as the size of the lists varies i am very confused in how to do that without the need of a lot of precoding based on a crazy amount of ifs and the size of the list.

also is there a difference in calling product(range(3)) or product(xrange(3))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def bigproduct(*args):
  newargs = [xrange(x) for x in args]
  return itertools.product(*newargs)

for i in bigproduct(3, 2, 4):
   ....
```

`range()` generates a list up-front, therefore uses time up front and more space, but takes less time to get each element. `xrange()` generates each element on the fly, so takes up less space and initial time, but takes more time to return each element.

Comment: +1 Let me add two details: 1) In Python 3, `range()` behaves like `xrange()` 2) In the CPython implementation of Python 2, `xrange` is limited to the C `long` data type (i.e. `xrange(int(2**31-1))` is typically the max range). Hit that one once...

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily accomplished using map:

```
from itertools import product
for i in product(*map(range, shape)):
    print i
```

Comment: what is `shape`? is this a numpy-specific reference?